# Downloading project files with svnkit is extremely slow

Tags: java, performance, svn, svnkit

I am a researcher who tries to monitor and study the evolution of projects. For this reason I use a client that uses svnkit to connect to remote respositories and download java projects in order to calculate metrics, perform analyses etc.

The problem is that the process of downloading from svn repositories is extremely slow. For example my program is being downloading the LAST revision of a small project with a total of 219 revisions, for the past 3 hours!

Is there a time to speed up this process?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's my experience with svnkit, too. Use someting else, like the Native JavaHL connector, TortoiseSVN, or the basic command-line svn.

Comment: maybe downloading data [parallel](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) helps.

Comment: Can't you simply send SVN where it belongs to? Cloning whole [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git) with 2000 commits takes 30 seconds.